PHPStan defining custom callback for Builder::when()
Question below. I need a searchable list of a certain resource, so:
$users = User::query()
    ->when(
        value: $this->search,
        callback: fn($query) => $query->where('name', 'like', "%$this->search%")
    )
    ->get()

Sometimes you want to search on multiple columns, so:
...
        callback: fn($query) => $query->where(fn($query) => $query
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', "%$this->search%")
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', "%$this->search%")
            ->orWhere('nickname', 'like', "%$this->search%")
...

Hey let's pull that logic into a reusable method:
public function searchable(array $columns):array
{
    return [
        $this->search,
        fn($query) => $query->where(function ($query) use ($columns) {
            foreach ( $columns as $column ) {
                $query->orWhere($column, 'like', "%$this->search%");
            }
        })
    ];
}

...
$users = User::query()
    ->when(...$this->searchable([
        'name',
        'email',
        'nickname',
    ]))
    ->get()


This code works beautifully in testing. My problem is, I need to tell PHPStan what I'm doing. (I've gotten pretty good at PHPStan in the last 2 months, but this is stumping me.) Here's the furthest I've gotten:
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

    /**
     * @template TModel of Model
     * @template TBuilder of Builder<TModel>|HasMany<TModel>
     *
     * @param list<string> $columns
     * @return array{
     *     0:string,
     *     1:callable(TBuilder):TBuilder|void
     * }
     */
     public function searchable(array $columns):array

PHPStan says:
Parameter #2 $callback of method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder<App\Models\User>::when() expects                                                                   
    (callable(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder<App\Models\User>,                                                                                                         
    callable(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder<Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model>|Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany<Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model>):       
     (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder<Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model>|Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany<Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model>)|string|void):  
         mixed)|null,                                                                                                                                                                 
         (callable(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder<Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model>|Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany<Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model>):      
         (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder<Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model>|Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany<Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model>))|void          
         given.                                                                                                                                                                       
          Type #1 from the union: Template type TModelClass on class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder is not covariant. Learn more:                                             
            https://phpstan.org/blog/whats-up-with-template-covariant 

Please, any help? TIA

Perhaps this is the same or a similar issue as described in PHPStan GH issue 9559 Bad guess for named params in complex spread call
